# Why does Resharper think that an inner class with property "SomeValue" hides a property with the same name in the outer class?

Tags: c#, resharper

Given the following code:

```
public static class Super
{
    public static class Inner
    {
        public static string SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public static string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Resharper tells me that `Super.Inner.SomeValue` hides a property from the outer class.

How is there hiding going on?  You have two distinct references (`Super.SomeValue` and `Super.Inner.SomeValue`).  And (as far as I know) you cannot use one reference to mean the other variable.

I have found that Resharper is wrong sometimes.  But not usually.  So I would like to know what it is thinking here.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think it's rather called a nested class than subclass, which is more relevant for a derived class ;-)

Comment: @Seb - good point.  I changed the title.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm guessing because it means using `SomeValue` in the inner class means you get the value assigned to the inner class rather than the outer class.

Consider this:

```
public static class Super
{
  public static class Sub
  {
    public static string OtherValue {get{return SomeValue;}}

    // Remove this line and OtherValue will return Outer
    public static string SomeValue { get{return "Inner"; }}
  }

  public static string SomeValue { get{return "Outer"; }}
}
```

Currently `Super.Sub.OtherValue` will return `Inner` but removing the line I've commented will cause it to return `Outer`

Comment: It doesn't stop you from accessing it, but you have to qualify the reference; var someValue = Super.SomeValue;

Comment: Yeah, bad choice of words, will change it.

Comment: I see now.  I was looking at it backwards.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I too was confused about this message. But it makes sense that this is about consuming the field from within the nested class. A consumer on the outside can still access them explicitly without any "hiding" tripping you up.